# loading classes from other files with Class.forName (ClassNotFoundException)

Tags: java, exception

i solved the problem with a $ instead of the . in the class path, so instead of: "us.ryphael.amongus.tasks.Download.startDownloadTaskRunnable"
"us.ryphael.amongus.tasks.Download$startDownloadTaskRunnable"
(a "$" for a nested class)

so i am making a amongus plugin for minecraft with java(but i don't think this matters for the question) and i want to give a class to every one of the values of an enum, but i don't want to make a new class when i "instantiate" the enum entry's. This is because i need to change the variables with witch i instantiate the class according to things that can change. (i don't know if anyone is going to get this explenation so please tell me if you don't)
So i tried to do this with Class.forName, so i can only give the class name to the enum entry and "instantiate" the class later, but the classes that i want to give to the enum are in another java class file and it gives me a ClassNotFoundException every time. (I think i am not searching for the class in the right way or it's just impossible to do this but i don't know).

For extra information:

"us.ryphael.amongus.tasks.Download.startDownloadTaskRunnable" is a class that implements the Runnable class

and i only want to "instantiate" that class (with "new") if i run the COMS_DOWNLOAD.runtask(DUMMYPLAYER) function because i need to give the class a player ("DUMMYPLAYER") that can change.

I hope you can help!

This is the full enum:

```
public enum ButtonTasks {

COMS_DOWNLOAD("coms_download", 14, 4, 30, 14, 4, 29, "us.ryphael.amongus.tasks.Download.startDownloadTaskRunnable");

private final Location button_location;
private final Location block_location;
private final Class runnable;
private final String naam;

ButtonTasks(String naam ,int button_x, int button_y, int button_z, int block_x, int block_y, int block_z, String runnableName){
    this.naam = naam;
    Class runnable1;
    try {
        runnable1 =Class.forName(runnableName);
        Bukkit.getLogger().info("De task " + naam + " is geladen!");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        runnable1 = null;
        Bukkit.getLogger().warning("De class " + runnableName + " is niet gevonden! " + naam + " werkt nu niet!");
    }

    this.runnable = runnable1;
    this.button_location = new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("world"), button_x, button_y, button_z);
    Block button = Bukkit.getWorld("world").getBlockAt(new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("world"), button_x, button_y, button_z));
    FaceAttachable fa = (FaceAttachable) button.getBlockData();
    this.block_location = new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("world"), block_x, block_y, block_z);
}

public void runTask(Player player){
    Runnable runnable2;
    if (runnable != null) {
        try {
            runnable2 = (Runnable) runnable.getDeclaredConstructor(Player.class).newInstance(player);
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            runnable2 = null;
        }
    }else{
        runnable2 = null;
    }
    if (runnable2 != null) {
        Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(Amongus.get(), runnable2);
    }else{
        Bukkit.getLogger().warning("De runnable is niet gevonden! " + naam + " werkt nu niet!");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why not just pass the Class as a literal, instead of its name as a String?

Comment: This is not possible because i would need to instantiate the class with "new" right?
And i can't do this outside of the function...

Comment: Each class has a static member variable, named `class`, that holds a reference to the `Class` object, e.g. `us.ryphael.amongus.tasks.Download$startDownloadTaskRunnable.class`. So instead of passing the class name as a string, pass the `Class` object.